# Ação 'onlogin' - Plugin de botões do Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugin, app

Tenho um App no Facebook, e na página inicial possui um botão para caso o usuário não esteja logado no Facebook, o mesmo fazer. Esse botão é um plugin do próprio Facebook. Li toda a documentação desse plugin, e esse botão de login especificamente tem uma configuração chamada 'onlogin', para caso for preciso, eu execute alguma função JS após o login for processado com sucesso.

Logo após o processo do login ser feito, eu precisava que na página inteira fosse feito um *reload* simples. Está dessa forma (simples de tudo!):

```
<script>
     function reloadPage(){
        window.location.reload();
 }
 </script>
```

Aqui é o plugin pronto do botão onde chamo a função no `onlogin`:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="email" onlogin="reload()"></div>
```

O caso é que simplesmente não funciona! Como posso fazer isso de alguma outra forma?

Comment: O nome da sua função não bate com o que está no onlogin!

Answer (score 1):

No evento onlogin do botão, o nome da função que será chamada é `reload`.

A função que você definiu chama-se `reloadPage`.

Mude de `reload` para `reloadPage`:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="email" onlogin="reloadPage"></div>
```

Código de exemplo usado no teste: https://gist.github.com/bzxbot/5064dae3bc64ff6b9349

Para que a página seja redirecionada, e não o iframe, use top.location, ao invés de window.location.

Comment: Desculpa cara, escrevi o nome da chamada da função errado ai. Mas mesmo assim, não funciona. =/

Comment: Qual o DOCTYPE da sua página? A propriedade onlogin é válida somente para HTML5.

Comment: O DOCTYPE já está definida como html5.

Comment: Adicionei uma página de exemplo, faça o teste com ela e verifique se a mensagem é exibida no console. Lembre-se de trocar APPID pelo identificador do seu aplicativo.

Comment: Ele só da um reload no iframe do app... há alguma forma de recarregar a página inteira?

Comment: Alterei o código de exemplo para fazer o redirecionamento. Dê uma olhada. Basicamente, uso o top.location para fazer o redirecionamento.

Comment: Valeu Bernardo! Salvou minha vida. :D Valeu mesmo!